# Typescript: How to type combined reducers?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I am migrating my small React Native project from pure Javascript to Typescript. While it went well so far, I now have problems with Redux.

The reducer I'm struggling with is `radioButtonSelectedReducer`. In the application, there are two radio buttons. If the first one is clicked, it gives string "itemOne" and if the second one is clicked, it gives string "itemTwo". Therefore, `radioButtonSelected` must be of type string, I thought. But it gives the error: `radioButtonSelected: string;` -->

```
"The expected type comes from property 'radioButtonSelected' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject<IApplicationState, AnyAction>'"
```

I am such a Typescript newbie and don't know what to do with this message.

```
imports ...

export interface IApplicationState {
  radioButtonSelected: string;
  searchBarInput: string;
  searchBarResult: string;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IApplicationState>({
  radioButtonSelected: radioButtonSelectedReducer,
  searchBarInput: searchBarInputReducer,
  searchBarResult: searchBarResultReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

When I leave `combineReducers()` without `<IApplicationState>` and call `RootState` in `mapStateToProps()`, it gives the error:

```
  error TS2339: Property 'itemSelected' does not exist on type 'CombinedState<{ radioButtonSelected: { itemSele
cted: string; }; searchBarInput: { inputValue: any; }; searchBarResult: { returnValue: any; }; }>'.
```

Here is the snippet from the component that implements the radio buttons:

```
...

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    itemSelected: state.itemSelected,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have to declare `IApplicationState` or pass it as a generic to `combineReducers()`.  In fact, that's explicitly the point of `type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`.  It infers what the combined state type is, so you don't have to declare it or keep updating it.

Please refer to [the Redux docs page on "Usage with TypeScript"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried exactly this in the first run, but when I call mapStateToProps in the component, it says:  error TS2339: Property 'itemSelected' does not exist on type 'CombinedState<{ radioButtonSelected: { itemSele
cted: string; }; searchBarInput: { inputValue: any; }; searchBarResult: { returnValue: any; }; }>'. Updated my question.

Comment: That's because you aren't passing a field named `itemSelected` to `combineReducers`.  Either there's another reducer you forgot to add to the root reducer, or you've mismatched the field names (ie, `state.itemSelected` should actually be `state.radioButtonSelected`).