# How to add type on store and combine reducers in react-redux with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have this type error that breaks the app using react-redux with TypeScript.

Error:

[image]

This comes from `root_store.ts` file which creates my store:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const configureStore = () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];
  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);

  const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer];
  const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers);

  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composedEnhancers);
  const peristor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, peristor };
};
export const { store, peristor } = configureStore();
```

and on my root reducer. I have this code.

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({

  user
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

If I remove the type from `combineReducers fn` like `combineReducer<AppState>` I will have that error which I don't know why.

---

Here's the code for the user reducer:

```
const user = (state = userInitialState, action: UserActionTypes): IUser => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserEnumTypes.USER_INFO: {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      };
    }
    case UserEnumTypes.USER_LOGOUT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export default user;
```

Here's the code for the user actions:

```
export const setupUserOnSuccessLoginORSignup = (user: IUser): ISetupUserOnSuccessLoginORSignup => ({
  type: UserEnumTypes.USER_INFO,
  payload: {
    ...user
  }
});

export const logoutUser = (): ILogoutUser => ({
  type: UserEnumTypes.USER_LOGOUT,
  payload: {
    ...userInitialState
  }
});
```

Here's the action types for the users:

```
export enum UserEnumTypes {
  USER_INFO = 'USER_INFO',
  USER_LOGOUT = 'USER_LOGOUT'
}

export interface ISetupUserOnSuccessLoginORSignup {
  type: typeof UserEnumTypes.USER_INFO;
  payload: {
    id: number | null;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    createdAt?: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    usersGameGroups?: IUsersGameGroup[];
    posts?: IPost[];
  };
}

export interface ILogoutUser {
  type: typeof UserEnumTypes.USER_LOGOUT;
  payload: {
    id: number | null;
    username: string;
    email: string;
  };
}

export type UserActionTypes = ISetupUserOnSuccessLoginORSignup | ILogoutUser;
```

I followed this from redux guide **https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-reducers**

and read this opposite problem. [Typescript: How to type combined reducers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307199/typescript-how-to-type-combined-reducers)

Weird though because he didn't export the combineReducers but maybe he had it in single file.

---

I wanted to add `any` type in `const store:any = createStore(persistedReducer, composedEnhancers);` this will fix the error but is it advisable, my concern is I will lose the type checking when I map props to my component?

Comment: Looking at the error, I guess something is missing in your payload while you dispatch action, either I suggest you should have a look at typesafe-actions package. Instead of exporting a single type from actions, you can use this typesafe-actions package to ensure that your reducer method will receive correct payload from actions.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. So I checked every payload of each action and there was no missing property in my payload. all are properties are there.

Comment: Also, i tried extending my interfaces with Actions or AnyActions still has the same error